# LostFocus method of a text box getting executed before Form_Unload

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, controls, ms-access-2010

I am currently programming in MS Access VBA. I have a form with a textbox on it. I am executing some code on LostFocus event of the textbox.

However, when I close the form using mouse and by clicking on close button on right-top corner of the form, with cursor in the text box, I have noticed that LostFocus event is getting executed before Form_Unload event.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Also, where can I find priorities of the events?? Or How are priorities decided in VBA?

**EDIT:**

My exact application is like this.
I have a form in MS Access which is used for accepting users' login credentials.

[image]

I want to disble textbox for Password and Login button till a valid Username is entered. I check if the username is valid or not on onLostFocus event. Now, consider a case where this form is closed without entering anything in Username textbox. In that case, onLostFocus event gets executed before Form_Unload event.

However, for normal operation, I require onLostFocus event because, on that event I enable Password textbox and login button.

Could there be a different way of doing it??

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

Comment: @Konstant What have Excel events to do with MS Access?

Comment: Jay, you will need to provide code to get a proper answer. I provide a partial answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*I check if the username is valid or not on onLostFocus event.*"

Do your validation in the after update event of the username text box ... enable/disable the password text box as appropriate when the username value changes.

You can initially disable the the password text box at form load, assuming the form loads with the username text box empty.

Answer (score 3):

The lost focus event is not usually the best event for code. Did you have a specific reason for using it? If so, you will need to add a condition to the execution.

The order of events for an Access form are:

> Exit → LostFocus
>
> If you are closing a form, the Exit and LostFocus events occur before
>   the events associated with closing the form (such as Unload,
>   Deactivate, and Close), as follows:
>
> Exit (control) → LostFocus (control) → Unload (form) → Deactivate
>   (form) → Close (form)

-- http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/order-of-events-for-database-objects-HP005186761.aspx

Comment: I have edited the original question. hope it has enough details.

Comment: The After Update event is more appropriate, but consider, why do you want to do this? Usual security demands that you have a username **and** password, so both checks should be carried when you click the log in button. It will be *much* less annoying for the user.

Comment: Yes you are right. The requirement of validating like this is that as per the requirements, the authentic users also might not have their details added in the database and hence a check at username level would allow to actually distinguish if the details of the users are there in database or not. If they are not there, it will not enable password field. If user details are there in tables, then only password acts as security feature (though less secure than the way you suggested.)

Comment: If their details are not there, they do not have a password, so it does not matter what junk they fill in the password field, the search will fail as not found. 'SELECT FROM table WHERE uname=@uname AND pword=@pword' Just add a message to contact admin if they think the sign-in should work. You are using MS Access, this is not high security.

Answer (score 0):

using onDirty or onChange is probably better for what you're doing if it is a control that you're inserting data into. There's a bunch of better choices than onLostFocus. Without knowing anything specific makes it tough to know how to help you more specifically. I'd say just try another on Event, because due to the nature of onLostFocus, it'd be impossible to prepare for this contingency.

Comment: I tried using onDirty event instead of onLostFocus event. I could not achieve the same results. Please refer the the updated question for more details.